# JasperReports - table element and empty dataset

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Is it possible to make <jr:table> element display something similar to No data band if its dataset is empty, or is using subreport the only solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `<PrintWhenExpression>` to hide the normal table element, and a complimentary `<PrintWhenExpression>` for another empty table that indicates no data.

```
<componentElement>
    <reportElement key="table 2" style="table 2" x="90" y="0" width="360" height="140">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[true]]></printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
   <jr:table .....
</componentElement>
<componentElement>
    <reportElement key="table 3" style="table 2" x="90" y="0" width="360" height="140">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[false]]></printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
   <jr:table .....
</componentElement>
```

Comment: I tried that idea too, but I couldn't produce an expression that would tell me whether a specific dataset is empty or not...